# Find closes element on input change and show tooltip

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, onchange, closest

I need to find closest element fa-retweet when user change input name="qty" and on that element to show bootstrap tooltip...

I try with code:

```
$('input[name=qty]').change(function() { 
  $(this).closest('.fa-retweet').tooltip('show'); 
 });
```

but nothing happend. please help.

UPDATE with full html code:

```
<form method="post" action="/updateCart/35c3d0bd350dba471e8270d0f61e559d" accept-charset="UTF-8">
<input name="_method" type="hidden" value="post">
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="3r2qqrgYG62HVB5xkOOJYN5lVm5v4TNWK5ECQcoH"> 
<div class="col-md-1 col-xs-4" style="padding:0px; ">
  <input class="margin-mobile" type="number" name="qty" id="qty" value="3" style="width:40px; height: 30px; margin-top:5px; text-align: center !important; border: 1px solid #cf931e; color: #cf931e;">
</div>
<div class="col-md-2 col-xs-4 text-right" style="padding:0px;">
  <h2 class="text-theme" style="font-size:36px !important; margin-top:0px !important;">£96    
<sup style="position: relative;vertical-align: baseline;line-height: 0;font-size: 14px;top: -1.2em;">
00  </sup>  </h2>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2 col-xs-4 text-right" style="margin-top:5px;">
  <h3 style="margin:0px !important;"><button type="submit" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Click here to change quantity!" class="text-theme btn-non"><i style="margin-right:-5px;" class="fa fa-retweet" aria-hidden="true"></i></button> | <a href="/remove/35c3d0bd350dba471e8270d0f61e559d" class="text-theme"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></h3>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Try putting the `qty` in quotes: `$("input[name='qty']")`. Also, are you getting any errors?

Comment: no, there is no errors

Comment: Where is the full code?

Comment: I update with full code

Answer (score 0):

`.closest()` search **up the DOM tree** until it finds a match for the supplied selector, but `.fa-retweet` located not on this way.

This will work: `$(this).closest('form').find('.fa-retweet').tooltip('show');`

**UPD.** As mentioned in the [docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#markup-1):

> The required markup for a tooltip is only a **data** attribute and **title**
>   on the HTML element you wish to have a tooltip.

But in your variant tag `<i`> doesn't have data and title, but you have this inside `<button>`. So just make this:

```
$(this).closest('form').find('button').tooltip('show');
```

Or look at the example with your code: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/70hxsd5d/)